# how to overlap a horizontal gallery with a vertical gallery

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I'm an android-newbie and I'm looking for a solution, how to overlap a horizontal-scrolling  image-gallery with a vertical-scrolling image-gallery. that means one transparent image of the vertical-scrolling gallery should overlap one image of the horizontal-scrolling gallery (like a cross).

furthermore it should be possible to scroll either vertical or horizontal so that the image of the vertical-scrolling gallery or the image of the horizontal-scrolling gallery will change. is there an way ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but what about a 3x3 table layout like so:

`--VG--`

`HGIVHG`

`--VG--`

where VG means vertical gallery, HG is horizontal gallery, IV is an image view and -- is just an empty frame layout.

Now, you have two image lists, the vertical and the horizontal list. You remember the image list states and always recognize the focused images in your data model. The two focused images are composed in the centered image view, whereas the remaining images are distributed in the adjacent galleries. It's a bit of effort but should work.

Comment: anselm's answer makes sense in more or less any programming language - Another user has posted a similar question - you guys should exchange ideas and thoughts - that question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346108/android-how-to-build-a-2d-dimension-gallery-with-vertical-and-horizontal-swipi/8346439#8346439